# How to set a countdown and loop the seconds in HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to do a countdown and put it in my website. I did a countdown but I have a problem, when I launch it, the seconds are freezing they are not anymore running...
Here is what I did:

```
<span id="dhour"></span> h <span id="dmin"></span> min <span id="dsec"></span> sec
<div id="count2"></div>
<div class="numbers" id="dday" hidden="true"></div>
<script>
    var montharray = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");
    var year;
    var month;
    var day;
    var hour = 19;
    var minute = 10;
    var tz = 0;
    var ladate;
    var today;

    function myCallback(json) {

        ladate = new Date(json.dateString);

        year = ladate.getFullYear();
        month = ladate.getMonth() + 1;
        day = ladate.getDate();
        countdown(year, month, day, hour, minute);
    }

    function countdown(yr, m, d, hr, min) {
        theyear = yr;
        themonth = m;
        theday = d;
        thehour = hr;
        theminute = min;
        today = ladate;
        var todayy = today.getYear();
        if (todayy < 1000) {
            todayy += 1900;
        }

        var todaym = today.getMonth();
        var todayd = today.getDate();
        var todayh = today.getHours();
        var todaymin = today.getMinutes();
        var todaysec = today.getSeconds();
        var todaystring1 = montharray[todaym] + " " + todayd + ", " + todayy + " " + todayh + ":" + todaymin + ":" + todaysec;
        var todaystring = Date.parse(todaystring1) + (tz * 1000 * 60 * 60);
        var futurestring1 = (montharray[m - 1] + " " + d + ", " + yr + " " + hr + ":" + min);
        var futurestring = Date.parse(futurestring1) - (today.getTimezoneOffset() * (1000 * 60));
        var dd = futurestring - todaystring;
        var dday = Math.floor(dd / (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24) * 1);
        var dhour = Math.floor((dd % (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24)) / (60 * 60 * 1000) * 1);
        var dmin = Math.floor(((dd % (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24)) % (60 * 60 * 1000)) / (60 * 1000) * 1);
        var dsec = Math.floor((((dd % (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24)) % (60 * 60 * 1000)) % (60 * 1000)) / 1000 * 1);

        if (dday <= 0 && dhour <= 0 && dmin <= 0 && dsec <= 0) {
            document.getElementById('count2').style.display = "inline";
            document.getElementById('after').style.display = "none";

            document.getElementById('dday').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('dhour').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('dmin').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('dsec').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('days').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('hours').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('minutes').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('seconds').style.display = "none";
            return;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('count2').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('dday').innerHTML = dday;
            document.getElementById('dhour').innerHTML = dhour;
            document.getElementById('dmin').innerHTML = dmin;
            document.getElementById('dsec').innerHTML = dsec;
            setTimeout("countdown(theyear,themonth,theday,thehour,theminute)", 1000);
        }
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now.json?callback=myCallback"></script>
```

Thank you. 
 Hoping to fix this.

Comment: Where are you calling the function?

Comment: As commented above, you're not calling the function anywhere in displayed code. Also note that you've tagged this question as `jquery` and `php` while both aren't used or even mentioned in your question. This can lead people (like) to click on your question while they might not have a lot of knowledge about it.

Comment: in the javascript

Comment: And what about your title "by not using the PC time"? What is your problem?

Comment: Could you please clarify the "Not using the PC time" requirement? Do you want to launch an AJAX request per second to fetch server time?

Comment: I changed the title..

Comment: try to run the code here http://phpfiddle.org/ and you will see what I mean

Comment: With all due respect, but it's still unclear what exactly you want to do. You've posted code that runs fine. If you actually want to make the countdown realtime, there's hundreds of good examples on the internet, like this one: http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/MwNPVq/

Comment: the problem of my code is that the countdown is not realtime...

Comment: I don't want to use other examples, I need to use mine because it is appropriate for what I want

Answer (score 3):

If you do this:

```
function countdown(yr, m, d, hr, min) {
    /**/console.log(yr, m, d, hr, min);
}
```

... you'll see you're calling `countdown` with the same values every time.

Nothing in your code increments any of the variables:

```
setTimeout("countdown(theyear,themonth,theday,thehour,theminute)", 1000);
```

Comment: Even with what you add in the function the countdown is still not realtime

Comment: @Sheva07 Certainly, if you fix this there may be additional errors. I didn't perform a comprehensive bug report.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer from Álvaro González](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41551730/6738706) correctly describes why your code does not work as intended. I would suggest that you start over with a minimal working solution for a countdown, then update it incrementally with parts of your code, testing along the way that it still works, until you get your code fully working as intended. Below is a simple code example of a working countdown that may be expanded with custom code:

```js
function startCountdown(targetdate){
  var timerID = setInterval(function(){//repeat this function each 1000 ms
    //get current date updated at each repetition
    var now = new Date;
    //compare this to the target date
    var differenceInSeconds = Math.floor((targetdate - now) / 1000);
    //if targetdate has not yet been reached
    if(differenceInSeconds > 0){
      //display how much time left
      var message = differenceInSeconds + ' seconds left until ' + targetdate;
    } else {
      //display that countdown is over
      var message = 'Targetdate has been reached'
      //clear timer
      clearInterval(timerID);
    }
    document.getElementById('showCountdown').innerHTML = message;
  }, 1000); //set function to repeat every second
}

//start countdown, set to 15 seconds from the time it is started
startCountdown(new Date((+new Date) + 1000 * 15));
```

```html
<div id="showCountdown"></div>
```